# ADB access denied to data folder?

Tags: android, adb

I connected to my live device using the adb and the following commands:

```
C:\>adb -s HT829GZ52000 shell
$ ls
ls
sqlite_stmt_journals
cache
sdcard
etc
system
sys
sbin
proc
logo.rle
init.trout.rc
init.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init
default.prop
data
root
dev
$ cd data
cd data
$ ls
ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
```

I was surprised to see that I have access denied. How come I can't browse around the directories using the commandline like this?

How do I get root access on my phone?

Comment: Simple... make sure your phone screen is on. Click "Allow" when it asks if you want Unknown to have access to root. Done.

Comment: decided to create a simple avd to have access to the database. Does anyone have any links to guides, without "custom" flare and graphics for developers? Just how to get plain vanilla android on a purchased device.

Comment: No such prompt occurs on my Android 7.1.1 device. But adb goes ahead and lists contents of the directory. Trouble is, the contents don't actually exist. I'm using adb-sync to add contents. It's pretty weird.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you want to browse everything on your device, you need to do two things:

1. You need to have a phone with root access in order to browse the data folder on an Android phone. That means either you have a developer device ([ADP1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Dev_Phone#Android_Dev_Phone_1) or an [ION](http://www.engadget.com/2009/05/27/google-ion-hands-on-and-unboxing/) from Google I/O) or you've found a way to 'root' your phone some other way.
2. You need to be running ADB in root mode, do this by executing: `adb root`

> **Note** that if step-1 is done correctly, step-2 just works (no need to re-build anything from source-codes).

Comment: And "adb root" requires a custom build of adb, otherwise "adbd cannot run as root in production builds"

Comment: custom build of adb? where can I get it from?

Comment: @Gopinath: I believe you have to build it from source for the target device, configured to allow root using the ndk then flash it onto the device along with an image of the binary files.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not necessary to have a custom build of adb. It IS necessary to have *adbd* support running as root, but this adbd is on the device - so whatever modification was made to make the device have root access is enough.

Comment: @bortzmeyer Did you try giving yourself root privileges? After executing `adb root`, execute `su`.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy adb root does not result in shell. It just says:
"adbd cannot run as root in production builds"

Comment: @Gopinath Here is a custom build of adb: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28070414/1185900
Here is a claim that by setting 'ro.debuggable' to 1 in ./default.prop in initramfs.cpio will allow stock adb to 'adb root': http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833756
As nitzanms has said, a custom build of adb isn't strictly necessary, but will probably be quicker/easier than editing that initial ramdisk file.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. See the answer from Idolon below.

Comment: It works with run-as for me, see below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712173/7483211

Comment: If you're like me and are instead running a device through Android's Emulator another important point to keep in mind is that Images that include the "Play Store" can't be rooted, or at least not easily.  Make sure if you're running an emulated phone that your image doesn't include the play store and you should be able to "adb root" just fine.  It's probably why you're getting that error @bortzmeyer .  Android also makes mention of using images without the play store here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/get#on_emulator .

Comment: I have tried by using "adb root" but still not able to access ls /sdcard/Android/data/<package_name>/files in Android 11

Answer (score 255):

Starting from API level 8 (Android 2.2), for the debuggable application (the one built by Android Studio all the times unless the release build was requested), you can use the shell `run-as` command to run a command or executable as a specific user/application or just switch to the *UID* of your application so you can access its *data* directory.

List directory content of yourapp:

```sh
run-as com.yourapp ls -l /data/data/com.yourapp
```

Switch to UID of *com.yourapp* and run all further commands using that uid (until you call `exit`):

```sh
run-as com.yourapp
cd /data/data/com.yourapp
ls -l
exit
```

**Note 1**: there is a [known issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/cubyLmLNTXQ/wGRopPum69cJ) with some HTC Desire phones. Because of a non-standard owner/permissions of the `/data/data` directory, `run-as` command fails to run on those phones.

**Note 2**: As pointed in the comments by @Avio:
`run-as` has issues also with Samsung Galaxy S phones running Cyanogenmod at any version (from 7 to 10.1) because on this platform `/data/data` is a symlink to `/datadata`. One way to solve the issue is to replace the symlink with the actual directory (unfortunately this usually requires root access).

Comment: This works as you explained where you `run-as com.mypackage`. The problem I ran into is `sqlite3 /data/data/com.mypackage/databases/mydb` says "sqlite3: permission denied". Can sqlite3 only be run by root?

Comment: @styfle That's mean that either you don't have the permission to run `sqlite3` executable (or access folder where it is located), or there is no `sqlite3` at all on your phone (see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3645800/648313)

Comment: @styfle Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8433520/648313 for the possible solution of `sqlite3` issue you have.

Comment: Works like charm when it comes to listing files stored in the internal storage.

Comment: I had to change permissions on the file to be able to move it to my sdcard, because I couldn't cp it running as my application. So, 1) run-as com.package.example, chmod 777 databasefile.db. 2) exit, go to sdcard, cp /data/data/com.package.example/databases/databasefile.db . And step 3 should be reverting the 777 permissions

Comment: `run-as` has issues also with `Samsung Galaxy S` phones running `Cyanogenmod` at any version (from 7 to 10.1) because on this platform `/data/data` is a symlink to `/datadata`. One way to solve the issue is to replace the symlink with the actual directory, however, I've found more convenient to recompile `run-as` without the symlink check. (http://gitorious.org/android-enablement/system-core/trees/1f4d95296acf34a93128332441782a80c10845b4/run-as)

Comment: My package is unknown no matter how correctly I spell it into my terminal : (

Comment: This should be the answer marked correct as this is the right method to use for non-rooted phones.

Answer (score 58):

**before we start,** do you have a *rooted* phone? if not, I strongly suggest that it's time you make the jump. 99% of the tutorials that help you to do this require that you have a rooted phone (I know b/c I spent about an hour searching for a way to do it without having a rooted phone.. couldn't find any..) also if you think about it, your iPhone also has to be rooted to do this same task. So it's totally reasonable. More about rooting at end of answer.

from your command line type:

```
adb shell
```

this takes you to your android shell comand line (you should see something like this: `shell@android:/ $` now type:

```
shell@android:/ $run-as com.domain.yourapp
```

this should take you directly to the data directory of `com.domain.yourapp`:

```
shell@android:/data/data/com.domain.yourapp $
```

*if it doesn't (ie if you get an error) then you probably don't have a rooted phone, or you haven't used your root user privileges. To use your root user privileges, type `su` on the adb command line and see what happens, if you get an error, then you're phone is not rooted. If it's not, root it first then continue these instructions.*

from there you can type `ls` and you'll see all the directories including the dbs:

```
shell@android:/data/data/com.domain.yourapp $ ls

cache
databases
lib
shared_prefs
```

after that you can use sqlite3 to browse the dbase.. if you don't have it installed (you can find it out by typing `sqlite3`, if you get `command not found` then you'll have to install it. To install sqlite, follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878236/766570).

**about rooting:** if you've never rooted your phone before, and you're worried about it screwing your phone, I can tell you with full confidence that there is nothing to worry about. there are tonnes of quick and easy phone rooting tutorials for pretty much all the new and old models out there, **and you can root your phone even if you have a mac** (I rooted my s3 with my mac).

Comment: You don't need a rooted phone for `run-as` to work. I just tried it on a production-build Galaxy Nexus S.

Comment: @TedHopp and so b/c it works just fine on your production-build Galaxy Nexus S.. it will work just fine on all android phones right?

Comment: @TedHopp personally i'm not much of an android developer.. and so instructions like `build the application as debuggable (either by building it with the Eclipse, or ant debug command)` may sound trivial to you, but they kinda intimidate me. I guess my answer is more for people who are comfortable with rooting their android phones, but aren't well versed in the android dev world. But i'm glad we're having this discussion.. I want the readers of my answer to be aware of the other non-rooting alternatives

Comment: also keep in mind i never claimed that *all* phones must be rooted.. in the original answer I said %99 of tutorials require a rooted phone.. ;)

Comment: Great answer man. I am using a few different phones here, (MotoX, nexus4, LG G3, SGIII) and this is pretty good for all.

Comment: I tried run-as : on my Xiaomi phone which is too new for a root exploit yet, against a security app from Verisign.  adb said "Package xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not debuggable".  This is good news, since i want my security app to be secure.

Comment: I do not recommend rooting your phone if you actually use it as a phone. If its sitting on your desk for development only, i suppose the risk is much less, but you do not need to root it to get access to your development application.

Answer (score 58):

$ adb shell

$ cd /data

$ ls

***opendir failed, Permission denied***

---

You should do this:

```
$ adb shell

$ cd /data

shell@android:/data $ run-as com.your.package 

shell@android:/data/data/com.your.package $ ls
```

OK!

Comment: This works! A couple of things to be done before executing any commands. Once the developer options are enabled on the phone, we would also need to enable **USB debugging**. I also additionally enabled something on my phone (HTC M8) called **Select debug app** and chose my app. Could be standard on all phones...should be.

Comment: giving error `run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted`

Comment: This just shows the app's internal storage dir, right?

Comment: This might not what the asker wanted, but it works wonder for us android developers who want to see how is our app files organized inside an actual phone. With this, we can that there are cache folder, databases folder, files folder, shared_prefs folder, etc; and check all their contents.

Comment: @mufazmi I think it only works for app you developed. You can simply see facebook or instagram's folder contents. Unless your phone is rooted.

Answer (score 33):

I had a similar problem when trying to operate on a rooted Samsung Galaxy S. Issuing a command from the computer shell

```
> adb root
```

fails with a message "cannot run as root in production builds". Here is a simple method that allows to become root.

Instead of the previous, issue the following two commands one after the other

```
> adb shell
$ su
```

After the first command, if the prompt has changed from '>' to '$' as shown above, it means that you have entered the adb shell environment. If subsequently the prompt has changed to '#' after issuing the second command, that means that you are now root. Now, as root, you can do anything you want with your device.

To switch back to 'safe' shell, issue

```
# exit
```

You will see that the prompt '$' reappears which means you are in the adb shell as a user and not as root.

Comment: I get an error that 'adb root' doesn't work in production builds.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Btw you need to have a rooted phone to do this. You may also need SuperSU or something similar? At least when I tried to use "su" SuperSU gave me a dialog on my phone.

Comment: /system/bin/sh: su: not found

Comment: what is su not found?

Comment: Thank you :) the `adb shell + su` solved the annoying permission thing forever. I had a problem about `su: not found` on Android 4.3 but since i upgraded to 4.4.2 problem disappeared. 4.3 seems to have problems.

Comment: su is not available to me, Nexus 5 / Android 5.1 - is there a workaround?

Answer (score 19):

I had a lot of trouble with this also. I still don't fully understand the permission and root run, but this worked for me (one of the previous answers partly) to copy database file from /data/data/[package name]/databases/my_db.db . Running *shell root*, or *su* in shell for some reason didn't work, nor did copying the db file (I could navigate to the directory though), nor did *sqlite3*.

So, this worked! In DOS command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
1|shell@android:/ $ run-as de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps
run-as de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps
1|shell@android:/data/data/de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps $ cd /data
cd /data
shell@android:/data $ cd data
cd data
shell@android:/data/data $ cd de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps
cd de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps
shell@android:/data/data/de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps $ cd databases
cd databases
shell@android:/data/data/de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/databases $ ls
ls
bus_timetable_lines.db
bus_timetable_lines.db-journal
shell@android:/data/data/de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/databases $ cat bus
_timetable_lines.db > /sdcard/db_copy.db
 bus_timetable_lines.db > /sdcard/db_copy.db                                   <
shell@android:/data/data/de.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/databases $exit   ^
exit
shell@android:/ $ exit
exit

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

Now go to SDCARD directory and get your file db_copy.db . Even that was hidden, but I managed to email it. Back in Windows, I was able to open db file with SQLite Database Browser. :)

Comment: I tried ->       run-as <app_package_name>                                                       But the adb didnt not recognized my app_package_name. I used the package_name that I specified in my AndroidManifest.xml.                              Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

This works if your Android device is rooted by any means (not sure if it works for non-rooted).

1. `adb shell` - access the shell
2. `su` - become the superuser.

You can now read all files in all directories.

Answer (score 4):

Following are the two steps to get root access:

1. Your android devices must be rooted.
2. In ADB shell, type su and the android device will prompt y/n? You choose allow.

Comment: type su.. will give prompt on mobile device.. asking for super permission through Superuser ..it worked

Answer (score 3):

production builds can't enter /data/app

```
drwxrwx--- system   cache             1970-01-01 08:00 cache
drwxrwxr-x root     system            1970-01-01 08:00 mnt 
drwxrwx--x system   system            1970-01-01 08:15 data
```

might need change to right owner to operate it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that we need to specifically give adb root access in the developnent options in the latest CMs..
Here is what i did.

> abc@abc-L655:~$ sudo adb kill-server
>   abc@abc-L655:~$ sudo adb root start-server
>   * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
>   * daemon started successfully * root access is disabled by system setting - enable in settings -> development options

after altering the development options...

```
abc@abc-L655:~$ sudo adb kill-server
abc@abc-L655:~$ sudo adb root start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting adbd as root
abc@abc-L655:~$ adb shell
root@android:/ # ls /data/ .... good to go..
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the application package you can `cd` directly to that folder..

eg  `cd data/data/com.yourapp`

this will drop you into a directory that is `read/writable` so you can change files as needed.  Since the folder is the same on the `emulator`, you can use that to get the folder path.

Comment: I can cd to the folder directly, but I still get the "opendir failed, permission denied" error.

Comment: This is because adb's "shell" user has execute permission on the directories, but not read permission.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see your **DB & Tables** then the esiest way is to use `Stetho`. Pretty cool tool for every Android developer who uses `SQLite` buit by `Facobook developed`.

`Steps to use the tool`

1. Add below dependeccy in your application`s gradle file (Module: app)

> 'compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'

2. Add below lines of code in your Activity onCreate() method

> ```
> @Override
>  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>  Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
>  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>  }
> ```

Now, build your application & When the app is running, you can browse your app database, by opening chrome  in the url:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

Screenshots of the same are as below_

> ChromeInspact

[image: ChromeInspact]

> Your DB

[image: Your DB]

Hope this will help to all! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You phone should be rooted. This is an important step!
2. Go to the adb file location and start command prompt as an admin on that location
3. run below commands:

```
adb shell
run-as com.domain.yourapp
```

this will ask root access on your phone, allow it.

4. You will be able to browse files using root access.
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is pretty old but I encountered this problem today while trying to copy my database files from within android studio to my windows to read it. I didn't need to run any commands, in fact nothing at all in that manner. Only thing I did was reconnect the USB plugged to my device and when the prompt that says "use USB for" came up, I selected "file transfer" and it worked! No need for you to have a rooted device to copy its inner files.

Answer (score -5):

When you are in the shell directory for the device. Just run

```
su - root
```

Then you should be able to access the data/ folder.

Answer (score -6):

**without rooting** the device you can access the files by the following
The cmd screenshot:
[image]

1. start the adb using cmd from the platform-tools folder according to your user

   ```
   cd C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
   ```

   it can be in another folder depends on where you installed it.
2. display the working devices.

   ```
   adb devices
   ```

   for say the respond os the command is

   ```
   List of devices attached
   0123456789ABCDEF     device
   ```
3. write the command

   ```
       adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell "su"
   ```

   it will open in

   ```
       root@theDeviceName:/ #
   ```

4.Accessing files, list all the files

```
ls
```

and so-on chang directory to any where else like the data folder

```
cd data/data
```

Comment: C:\Users\bruker\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb -s emulator-5554 shell "su"
/system/bin/sh: su: not found

Comment: in my case it was android 5.0.2 i don't know if it differ from version to another @Koen

Comment: the path depends on where you installed android studio and it's SDKs @Solo

Comment: The problem isn't finding where adb is. It is in my PATH. Getting the files list (or even executing `su`) doesn't work/isn't allowed. Testing with Android 4.3.

Comment: su is not found

Comment: it works, but how can I pull the file to local?