# Does Developing Android Applications require a Rooted Device?

Tags: android, root, rooted-device

I am looking generally in to Android development.

I keep seeing information on [root](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Why_Root) however I am unclear how this relates to general android app development.

I understand that there is an emulator however when I get to actually test the software on a phone does that phone have to be a rooted device or is this only required if you wish to edit the core features of the os?

Finally are there are any development disadvantages to rooting the device such as that is no longer behaves like other android phones I may deploy too?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need root to develop for Android.

The easiest setup is to run Eclipse with the Android Development Tools installed.  Then, you can debug your application in the emulator, or register your phone with the SDK and debug directly on your phone.  The only thing you need to do on your phone is check the development mode under *Settings -> Applications*

I can understand the allure of having a rooted device, but I can't really see a reason for changing the bootloader or os binaries.  You can, however, change most of the default applications (including the Home application) with other applications available on the Market.  For instance, OpenHome is about $5 and allows you to replace the home app, add themes, and replace many of the core apps (e.g. clock).

Comment: There are some development-related things you cannot do without root like loading your application's database to your PC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078710/android-adb-access-to-application-databases-without-root

Comment: Yes, you need root for downloading your application's database, but as alternative you can use emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Rooting is only required, if you want to play around with advanced features or update your firmware, etc.

If you develop your software using the Android SDK you will be able to use it on your phone regularly (as long as you have the corresponding version). No rooting needed.

I have never heard of any problems according to your concerns. But I cannot deny that there are none. Though I personally don't expect that there are any problems with rooted phones.

Comment: FYI - I think this is important enough reason to point out specifically, rooting is needed if you want to copy the sqlite DB off the device for examination in a desktop client.

Answer (score 2):

On the Nexus S running Android 2.3, the /data folder is not visible in the DDMS File Explorer or the ADB shell, but it is visible in the emulator. This occurred with debug turned on in both the manifest and on the phone. I confirmed that debug mode was properly enabled by successfully stepping through the app using breakpoints and also by receiving messages from logcat.

Not being able to see the /data folder means that you will not be able to get your application's private data.