# Android MediaStore sqlite db location

Tags: android, mediastore

I am trying to find the sqlite database used by the MediaStore. As far as I understand, the MediaStore contains amongst others the playlists defined in the default Music app. I actually would like to duplicate a playlist, but the app does not allow that. Somehow I thought I could fix this if I just could find the actual db file. But I got completely sidetracked now, because I just cannot find the db. Btw, I am running FroYo.

Answer (score 14):

Having a look at the [Android source the class we're interested in seems to be `android.provider.MediaStore`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_mediaprovider/blob/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java) and in there, the `getDatabaseForUri()` method seems generate a different database for each external storage card and one called `internal.db`.

So I think the file you're interested in is:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/internal.db
```

However, my copy of that database doesn't have the `audio_playlists` table used in the Java source so I'm not certain this is right.

Comment: How do you access the data under /data. I am using ASTRO to browse the data on my phone, but /data is empty. I am not sure though whether this is because the directory is really empty or because of permission settings.

Comment: `/data` is owned by `root` so you're not going to be able to browse it with ASTRO on an unrooted phone.  Try connecting your phone to your development PC and using `adb shell`.  I think this runs with root permissions on all phones but I don't have an unrooted phone with me to check this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That helps a lot and explains also why I had such a hard time finding this file. Unfortunately, 'adb shell' does not seem to run as root on an un-rooted phone :( How hard can it be!?

Comment: @Hardy - Just had a quick Google - if you use `adb shell` and then run the `su` command you should get root access.  On an unrooted phone it seems only the `root` and `shell` users can use `su` but I guess `adb shell` runs as the `shell` users so it should work.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have permissions for that. Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078710/android-adb-access-to-application-databases-without-root

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do this is to use the [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to query [media store](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) and do any kind of modifications to the tables from there.

Quick example of how you would query all artists in the MediaStore.

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST };
            //managed query doesn't need startManagingCursor called on the cursor
            Cursor c = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Right. That's the programmatic way. I guess in this case I could just get hold of the Music player code in the first place and add a duplicate playlist function. My point, however, was that I wanted to do a quick hack, by editing the sqlite database directly using any sqlite GUI. I just wonder which file contains the db?

Comment: Ah I see, you didn't mention you wanted to use a sqlite GUI to do this. Well as long as you have a rooted phone you should have no issues pulling the DB. I'm gonna look into its location and get back to you.

Comment: Did you find the location of the db. I really cannot find it :(

Comment: Does the database contain FTS-Tables for full-text-search on playlist names and so on?

Answer (score 3):

the location is:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/internal.db
```

audio_playlists not in Tables, you can see it in Views.
sql tool is:sqliteman,ubuntu13.10

Answer (score 0):

For android 11 (Rooted stock version)

i found the database on this location

/data/data/com.android.providers.media.module/databases/internal.db (for system related files)

/data/data/com.android.providers.media.module/databases/external.db (for user related files).

** Please note add the world "module" to com.android.providers.media