# Can't pull database file from Android phone on 5.1

Tags: android, adb

I have a non-rooted Nexus 5 on Android 5.1.
I've tried multiple solutions described here [Android ADB access to application databases without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078710/android-adb-access-to-application-databases-without-root) in order to pull a debugable app database from the file system, but to no avail. Has anybody managed to make it work on 5.1 ?

When trying to copy to sdcard, I get `cp: /sdcard: Permission denied`

When trying to pull the file directly, I get `remote object '/data/data/packagename/databases/name.db' does not exist`

Comment: It is now that you've updated your answer in that question thread. Going to copy-paste your updated answer here for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been successfully answered by Alex P here - [android adb, retrieve database using run-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471780/android-adb-retrieve-database-using-run-as)

Here's a quick look at the answer:

> the command for Android 5.0+ to save
>   /data/data/package.name/databases/file would be:
>
> ```
> adb exec-out run-as package.name cat databases/file > file
> ```

Comment: It worked. but file got encrypted. its asking password/key to decrypt the db file. its wired :/