# Android browse SQLite database on phone

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I browse the SQLite database that I am creating in my app on my Android myTouch phone?

When I log in through adb shell, sqlite3 gives me a permission denied. Is there another way to check if my database and tables are actually being created, and if rows are being inserted?

I am not able to use the emulator, since it doesn't play videos etc. very well that is the main feature of my app, so I can only test on phone.

Comment: Have you rooted your phone? If so, try sudo sqlite3 to open your db. If not, root it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the database when developing on a phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811615/how-to-access-the-database-when-developing-on-a-phone)

Answer (score 4):

The entire database is a single file, so via the DDMS view in Eclipse or via the command line you can pull that file from the phone. You can then use [SQLite DataBase Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to view the contents, for example.

Comment: if the `data` folder in DDMS mode is empty, means I do not have any database there, right?

Comment: @sammiwei Not necessarily. Apprently your phone needs to be rooted to access the database on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Using this library you can browse your SQLite database directly from your application
https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android

Its a single java activity file ,just add the java file to your source folder you can view the tables in your app database , update ,delete, insert rows to you table .Everything from your app.

When the development is done remove the java file from your src folder thats it .

It helped me a lot .Hope it helps you too .

You can view the 1 minute demo here : http://youtu.be/P5vpaGoBlBY