# Can not access android /data folder

Tags: android

I want to get the `/data/data/packagename/databases/test.db`, but i can not get it "Permission denied".

I use adb shell to access data folder, it shows:

```
$ sudo adb shell
$ cd data
$ ls
ls: can't open '.': Permission denied
```

why?? I can access /system folder

Comment: If you are aceessing it from the emulator terminal then you can't.

Comment: are you trying to access the data folder from device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the database when developing on Android phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811615/how-to-access-the-database-when-developing-on-android-phone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a root user to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First your phone should be rooted, you can use https://www.kingoapp.com/ for that. 
Next, you should modify the permission of your app access, to do so you have to :

1. Locate your adb.exe folder (you can find it in your sdk folders)
2. Right click
3. open cmd here
4. Type:

   adb shell 
   su 
   chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/yourapp

Good luck