# How to access package folder(/data/pakcage_name) in android device

Tags: android

i need to access my app package folder in my device (nexus), but i can do this with eclipse file explorer feature. should i root my device just to do this ?

i have tried with ADB shell but it give me some error. thanks

Comment: if You have to root your device then you can access your package folder.the other solution is to download x-plore file manager from play store.you can access your package directory.

Comment: [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en]

Comment: hi dipali, i still can't open /data folder with this apps .

Comment: which device you are using now?

Comment: which data have you access in /data/ folder?

Comment: please open /sdcard/android/data/...folder..

Comment: not in sdcard. it under root .. because all application store their folder in /data/data not in /sdcard/android/data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device)

Answer (score 3):

if your device isn't root follow these steps to access that:

1- open adb

2- perform `$ sudo ./adb shell`

3- to access to data folder use *ran-as* command:

```
shell@android:/ $ run-as app.package.name
```

now, you can access to files of your project. but maybe you don't have permission use *chmod*

4- `shell@android:/data/data/app.package.name $ chmod 777 databases/database_ame`

and also you can put/get files in/from that such as

```
$ sudo ./adb pull /data/data/app.package.name/databases/database_ame /home
```

or

```
$ sudo ./adb push /home/database_ame /data/data/app.package.name/databases/database_ame
```

**Edit:**

By the way, if you work in linux I think you should install *ia32-libs*

Comment: when i try to open adb shell 
D:\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb.exe shell
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: device offline

what's wrong ?

Comment: no guy, open cmd there (go to D:\android-sdk-windows\tools and keep shift key + right click). and after that run commands

Comment: looks like windows, so type `D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb shell` then you can perform his comments `run-as app.package.name` and so on