# can't find file created in dir returned by getFilesDir()

Tags: android, filesystems, getfiles

One part of my app needs to write a data file out.
I use `getFilesDir()` and it gives me a path like this (after adding a file name):

```
 /data/data/com.casadelgato.zillaconfigdroid/files/Log.1378357559316.csv
```

I create a `PrintWriter` to the file, write a bunch of stuff to it, and close it.
No errors.

The problem is that I can't find  the file anywhere on my Android device.

Comment: you will root permission i guess. if its on emulator you can use file explorer and check

Comment: you can't access that dir on real devices.have a look at this question : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device`

Answer (score 0):

mention the file name in the path

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(path,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

write the file into the stream...and you get the file by passing the same file name

```
FileInputStream openFileInput = context.openFileInput(path);
```

read the input stream