# Android studio file explorer not showing files in data folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio and 'samsung tab 2' as my testing device. I want to see the files of my application. So i clicked the  'Monitor' button. Then i selected my device from device list and selected my application package.There is a Data folder in file explorer. But when i clicked on the data folder it shows nothing.When i run this application using emulator the file explorer shows the data folder and i can see every files in my application. how can i see my files inside the data folder when using device ?

Comment: You can't access read device data through adb without root access. Other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution based on the answer in stack overflow .
[How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device)

First i rooted the device .Then i modify the access permission of data folder using adb shell.
the code is

```
$ adb shell
$ su
# mount -o rw
1|root@android:/ # chmod -R 777 data/
```

Now i can access the files.Thank you @param for your valuable comment.

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea - do you have a rooted device? He says he does.