# Why dont I have permissions on my SD card using adb shell?

Tags: android

I was attempting to access the data data folder of an application without rooting . I followed [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device) and was able to access the folder.

Now I was trying to copy the required file from data/data to a folder in my SD Card , however I get a permission denied on it. In the thread I have referenced above , no body complained of this behaviour so I suppose it shouldn't happen at my end too .

This is exactly what I am doing

```
C:\AndroidSdk\platform-tools>adb shell
shell@D6503:/ $ run-as com.xxx.xxx
run-as com.xxx.xxx
shell@D6503:/data/data/com.xxx.xxx $ cp databases/xxx.db /storage/sdcard1/Pictures/ 
cp: /storage/sdcard1/Pictures/xxx.db: Permission denied
```

I have verified that the folder /storage/sdcard1/Pictures is accessible through shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me as well. This is what I did to access the contents of the data folder of my app in my **Nexus 5 (Android 5.0), without having root access or *chmoding* any file:**

1. Open a console where your ADB is located and execute:

   `adb backup -noapk com.your.packagename`

   You will be asked to accept the backup on your device. Accept it and don't use any password. Once the backup process is completed, you will have a file with .ab extension on your ADB folder.
2. The backup will be compressed in a special way, you can decompress it with this tool: [Android Backup Extractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/)

   To use it, unzip it and put the backup file (*.ab) on the same folder where the extractor (*abe.jar*) is. Then open a console there and execute the following command:

   `java -jar abe.jar unpack NAME_OF_BACKUP.ab NAME_OF_BACKUP.tar`

   Notice that the result of this operation will be a *.tar file, which can be opened or decompressed with  WinRAR or many other compression tools.
3. *OPTIONAL for SQLite Databases:* If you want to see the contents of the database, you can use this Firefox plug-in: [Firefox SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)