# How to access data/data files of Android without a terminal on the Android device

Tags: android, root

I have an Android 4.2.0 device that I have rooted with Kingo Root through a Windows machine. I also have a Unix machine available.

I want to be able to transfer and read the contents of the `data/data` folders of my device to my computer.

While I understand that I can use the adb shell (or a phone-installed terminal) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device), I don't have internet connection on my Android device to download and install a terminal.

Is there some way to transfer and read the contents of the `data/data` folders with the setup described above?

Comment: adb shell with "runas" is probably the best that you can do.

Comment: How do I do that? The SuperSU application says that SuperSU Pro is required to run adb shell, which I don't have since my phone doesn't have internet connection

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing that behavior. You shouldn't need root to run "adb shell" - I do it frequently on my unrooted phone. Perhaps you can disable  or uninstall SuperSU?

Comment: I'm confused as to what the problem is.  You have a rooted device, you can connect it to your Windows machine, open up a command prompt, and `adb shell` in.  `cd data/data/`, and you're in.  Once you know what files you want, you can pull them using `adb pull /data/data/someFolder/someFile.txt` (for a text file for example).

Comment: I do this on the Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get adb set up on your Windows machine.

I just did this on my Windows 8 machine with a rooted device:

```
C:\Users\dan>adb devices
List of devices attached
LGLS8859a5b706c device

C:\Users\dan>adb shell
root@jagc:/ # cd data/data/com.android.phone/databases
cd data/data/com.android.phone/databases
root@jagc:/data/data/com.android.phone/databases # ls
ls
callreject.db
callreject.db-journal
callsettings.db
callsettings.db-journal
ipcall.db
ipcall.db-journal
quickmessage.db
quickmessage.db-journal
root@jagc:/data/data/com.android.phone/databases # exit
exit

C:\Users\dan>adb pull /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/callreject.db
878 KB/s (16384 bytes in 0.018s)

C:\Users\dan>
```

You can also pull an entire folder like this:

```
C:\Users\dan>adb pull /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/
pull: building file list...
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/callsettings.db-journal -> ./callse
ttings.db-journal
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/callsettings.db -> ./callsettings.d
b
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/callreject.db-journal -> ./callreje
ct.db-journal
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/callreject.db -> ./callreject.db
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/ipcall.db-journal -> ./ipcall.db-jo
urnal
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/ipcall.db -> ./ipcall.db
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/quickmessage.db-journal -> ./quickm
essage.db-journal
pull: /data/data/com.android.phone/databases/quickmessage.db -> ./quickmessage.d
b
8 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
1132 KB/s (125016 bytes in 0.107s)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done this. How do I now copy these folders in data/data over to my Windows machine?

Comment: @Brad, each `adb pull` command will copy the file to your Windows machine.

Comment: @Brad, just updated the answer with an example of pulling folders.

Comment: I guess that would work but I get `pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped` but I know the file is in there when I `adb shell`  and then input `su` I can find the whole folder I want to pull

Comment: @Brad, maybe you could adb shell in, copy the files to a different location, then see if you can access them there.