# Where is SQLite data and other app saved files stored?

Tags: android, sqlite, data-storage

Am working on an APP that has a) SQLite database, and b) text files and other files that are saved internally during operation.    From what I read, app data is stored in a folder `data\data\(app name)`

Plugging my Motorola Moto X into my development computer, I can access the Internal Storage via the PC as a "drive".   The first folder, does NOT have a `data` folder but there is an `android` folder.   In that folder, there IS a `data`.  Within that folder are folders such as `com.ebay.lid`, `com.gopro.smarty`,`com.weather.weather` and several others, but my app I am working on is not listed.

I have created a SQLite database and saved a text file internally, but have no idea where they went.

Is this a Moto X issue, a Moto X issue accessing via the PC as a drive, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: You can only access stuff in data/data on a rooted device.  See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285335/how-to-access-data-data-files-of-android-without-a-terminal-on-the-android-devic

Comment: "Plugging my Motorola Moto X into my development computer, I can access the Internal Storage via the PC as a "drive"" -- despite what you're seeing, that is actually what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "I have created a SQLite database and saved a text file internally, but have no idea where they went" -- they are in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You have no direct access to it on production hardware.

Comment: You need to be rooted to see these folders.

Comment: You have to go to /data/data/con.your package/databases. If you dont have rooted device, and you are un debug mode, you can do in console adb -d shell and then run-as com.yourpackage so then you can access to your app data, such aa databases, shared preferences, cache, etc.

Comment: I also find this script : https://github.com/Pixplicity/humpty-dumpty-android that allows you to retrieve the database from a real phone then you can read the extracted database with a sqlite sotfware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is only available for the emulator. The main reason why you cannot do that is because you don't have access to the database of a real device.

you can see details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195052/5505361