# android how does the getFileDir method works

Tags: android, file

Can anyone explain or provide a link that explains how the getFilesDir() works. I know that it returns a path on the internal storage of the specific package name. But i wanted to know how does it returns the path? Is the folder directly created when the app is installed or is it created when the method is first called? and other similar questions.

Comment: there is no such method `getFileDir` in the android SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the stock implementation of `Context`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java), known as `ContextImpl`.

The implementation of `getFilesDir()`, as of Android 6.0, is:

```
@Override
public File getFilesDir() {
    synchronized (mSync) {
        if (mFilesDir == null) {
            mFilesDir = new File(getDataDirFile(), "files");
        }
        return createFilesDirLocked(mFilesDir);
    }
}
```

`createFilesDirLocked()` goes through some complicated gyrations to create the directory, if needed:

```
// Common-path handling of app data dir creation
private static File createFilesDirLocked(File file) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                // spurious failure; probably racing with another process for this app
                return file;
            }
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to create files subdir " + file.getPath());
            return null;
        }
        FileUtils.setPermissions(
                file.getPath(),
                FileUtils.S_IRWXU|FileUtils.S_IRWXG|FileUtils.S_IXOTH,
                -1, -1);
    }
    return file;
}
```

> Is the folder directly created when the app is installed or is it created when the method is first called?

AFAIK, it is created when the method is called. You can test this yourself: write an app, then install it on an emulator but don't run it. Use the Android Device Monitor or `adb shell` to see if the directory exists.

> and other similar questions

You are welcome to peruse the Java code for Android's framework classes at your leisure.

Comment: can we assess file from /data/data

Comment: @AmarbirSingh: On an emulator, yes.

Comment: @AmarbirSingh check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device

Comment: @GParekar i already go through the link but unable to get it!!

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible in real device to get it through app?

Comment: if you are testing on phone it needs to be rooted. For emulator as @CommonsWare has said you can access it on emulator. For that run a app on emulator open the AndroidDeviceMonitor in the File Explorer section you can see the data/data folder

Comment: @GParekar root is last option for real device anything other then this??