# Android - Camera OK Button not working - Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, camera

I am facing a very strange issue. After clicking a picture from camera activity , a confirmation page appears with three options (icons) - **OK , Retake and Cancel**.
The Retake and Cancel buttons are working fine but after **clicking on OK button - nothing happens**.Its not returning back to my activity. I have seen similar posts but none of them worked for me.I have given all the permission read write and camera.Below are some observations i made while dealing with the issue.

> 1.On **Android 5.0.1** - **LENEVO YOGA TAB 3** , Same Code , **Ok button working fine.**
>
> 2.On **Android 6.0** - **LENEVO YOGA TAB 3** , Same Code , **Ok button not working** (permissions added read , write and camera).
>
> 3.On **Android 6.0** - **LeEco 2**  , Same Code , **has NO Ok button** , so is returning back to activity after capture - **working fine** (permissions added read , write and camera).

Its how i am opening my camera activity

```
public final static String PRE_CAMERA_FILE_NAME = "my_image";

public final static String FILE_DIRECTORY =
        (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ?
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() :
                Environment.getDataDirectory()) + File.separator + "Images";

private void openCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File mCameraFile = new File(FILE_DIRECTORY,   String.valueOf(PRE_CAMERA_FILE_NAME + System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
    if(!mCameraFile.exists()){
        mCameraFile.mkdirs();
    }
    System.out.println("Path:=" + mCameraFile.getAbsolutePath());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mCameraFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", mCameraFile);
    } else {
        mCameraFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mCameraFile);
    }
    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCameraFileUri);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_TYPE_CAMERA);
}
```

OnActivityResult :

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (mOnFileChooseListener != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String path = "";
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TYPE_CAMERA) {
            path = mCameraFileUri.getPath();
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TYPE_UPLOAD_PDF_OR_PHOTO && data != null) {
            path = FileUtils.getFilePath(getContext(), data.getData());
        }
        mOnFileChooseListener.onFileSelected(path);
    }
}
```

**Permissions added .**

[[image]]

**Can anyone please answer why this is happening ? Thanks in advance .**

Comment: When you click OK button at that time your clicked picture saved in your External or Internal storage of device??

Comment: No , File is getting created but its not opening gives input/output error.

Comment: I think You have to add Marshmallow permission class for granting your application to Read,Write etc. For this see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504867/need-to-access-the-system-permission/40505346#40505346

Comment: But in other device with android 6 the same code is working fine.I have already added the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue.
In my case, the save path was not correct. I changed `sameFile.mkdirs()` on `sameFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`. 
In your case `mCameraFile.mkdirs()` сreates a directory with the file name.
My work code

```
File file = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        + File.separator
        + screenState.catalogKey,
        idImg.toString());
if (file.getParentFile().exists() || file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
    mOutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ConstantManager.I_CAMERA_RESULT);
}
```