# Android equivalent of "Download Container" for iOS

Tags: android, ios

While working on an iOS app, in the Xcode Devices panel there exists an option to download/replace the container (basically the app data) of an installed app.

[image]

Is there an equivalent mechanism for Android development?

Comment: What is "the container of an installed app"?

Comment: Have you checked my answer below, is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess by `App Data` you mean the data that the app is creating and saving it on the device or emulator (simulator in ios!)? if yes, then you could do that with `adb shell`

App data is stored at the directory

```
/data/data/com.you.yourpackagename/
```

refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876731/5993410) for explained details.