# Android - can access system/app but cannot access data/app

Tags: java, android, file

I have a **rooted** android phone. And Im trying to access `/data/app/` folder. Using adb shell it is pretty easy, however I want to access it programmatically.

**My android manifest:**

```
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
...
```

And there is a strange thing, I can easily access `system/app`, but there is no chance to get data or catalog names in `data/app`.

Some java code:

```
String data = Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath();       
String system = Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath();

File dir1= new File(system);
File dir2 = new File(data);

String[] ff1 = dir1.list(); // returns bunches of names/catalogs
String[] ff2 = dir2 .list(); // returns null
```

Where I did mistake? Thanks for help.

Related topics: [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same mistake, here is the solution:

```
String path = "/data/app/com.niceapp.hugepackage/base.apk";
File file= new File(path);
```

There is no posibility to get list of `/data/app/` , however you can access the file directly. FYI, this is the way to get all packages:

```
 List<String > pkg_path = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<PackageInfo> pkginfo_list = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
 List<ApplicationInfo> appinfo_list = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
      for (int x=0; x < pkginfo_list.size(); x++){
            PackageInfo pkginfo = pkginfo_list.get(x);
            pkg_path.add(appinfo_list.get(x).publicSourceDir);  //store package path in array
      }
```