# Data folder in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I am working in an android project in android studio and I have created a database using SQLite and a table inside of this database.So I have a problem when I want to appear the database.I have installed the DB Browser for SQLite,and have followed the steps for finding database like;Tools-Android-Android Device Monitor-File Explorer; but when I go to the the folder 'data' it does contain nothing(it should contain the folder data,and then database). I am using an AVD for emulation.Why it is empty?

Comment: It's likely empty because the permissions deny access as access is restricted to protect App data. You may find this useful [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device). Personally I use GenyMotion emulator which provides access. [This could perhaps be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues)

Comment: Actually I am using emulator not a real device.