# Can't find SQLite database (db3) file on my phone

Tags: sqlite, android-database

I am creating an android app using xamarin shared project.

I have created a database using SQLite to store user's username, password, email, and other information.

This is my code to create SQLite code but it doesn't matter bc I know it works. User can signup, login, go to home page where they can see list of user's information. This means I am able to select and insert data from UserDatabase.db3 database.

```
var fileName = "UserDatabase.db3";
var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, path);
```

Issue is that I can't see or find UserDatabase.db3.

What I can tell is SQLite database is store on user's phone and  .db3 file is hidding under location

```
 /Data/Data/com.companyname.AppName/File/
```

on google it said that some how I need to root my phone(What ever that means). But shouldn't there a way to see this find without rooting? maybe a desktop software that can access .db3 without rooting junk?

I also tried the following but db3 file was no where to find

```
Visual Studio > View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer
```

**If There is not other way to access my db3 file, than  maybe there is a work around?**

i guess I can just create a test page in my app where it display tables by using 'select' statment? Is this a good approch?

Comment: See: [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13006315/295004) and [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/3573). Alternately use emulator which should allow access.

Comment: In a real phone the database is installed in a location that is not accessible, you will need to get root access. You should be able to access it only from the application(xamarin) that created the database. Or if its installed on a memory card there are other ways but not advisable.

Comment: I tried accessing my db3 using visual studio but it didn't worked

Comment: @Morrison thanks but I dont feel confortable rooting my phone

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see your database,click on device file explore in Android studio->Click On Data->Click On Data->Click On "Your Package Name"->Click On Database->Here You Can See Your Database

Comment: under my package name, I only see two folders (Cahce, File) and both of them are empty