# Graphene OS (Android): Where does it store app's cache data?

Tags: android, caching

I'm using an app for audiobooks that allows you to download the book onto your device for offline use. I'm trying to locate that file, but can't figure out how and where is it stored. /Android/data/ directory seems to be empty, and yet the book has been downloaded, and app details page show that it is indeed using some storage. Could it be some kind of DRM BS (even though the book has been purchased) ?

I've tried using file browsers but to no avail.

Comment: Apps typically cache their data in places you can't browse, i.e. in their private app data directory `/data/data/the.package.name/cache/` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device

Comment: Android 13 no longer allows 3rd party apps to grant permission to Android folder and/or data folder.

Navigate to Data Folder
internal storage, the path is similar as: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/the.package.name/cache/`

Comment: So.. it's impossible without hacking, correct ?