Can Appium access app files without rooting device?
I need to access files (R/W) on an Android device with Appium (in Java), on Windows.
I'm getting acquainted to adb in order to at least know what path is expected for /data, /Download, etc., but it seems that it lacks permissions, even for the AUT data files.
I think the path itself is different from what I see on the device & PC, after searching here and there and noticing the "Internal storage" part is translated to the local language. But I don't know how to find it so it's recognized by Appium.
I tried commands such as this on the terminal:
adb shell ls -R
Which gave me irrelevant files as well as lots of:
map_files: Permission denied
ns: Permission denied
./proc/1286/task/1286/cwd: Permission denied
./proc/1286/task/1286/root: Permission denied
./proc/1286/task/1286/exe: Permission denied
fd: Permission denied
fdinfo: Permission denied
ns: Permission denied

Even when running terminal as administrator.
As for an adb command launched from my program, such as:
        String cmd = " adb devices";
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("sudo C:\\Users\\myUser\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe", cmd);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

It is simply not seen anywhere (neither Appium server log nor standard output).
My ultimate goal is to manipulate files; my command was:
`driver.pushFile("[can't find the expected filesystem mapping anywhere!!!] \\storage(maybe??)\\Download\\bird.jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Downloads\\bird.jpg"));`

Which fails (once again, even with appium launched as administrator) with:
`adb: error: failed to copy 'C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\2024826-17660-y8us7v.ja5ka\appium.tmp' to '\storage\Download\bird.jpg': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system`

So are all Appium testers rooting their devices to be able to do data manipulation (even with their own app's /data) ?
Is there another way to access, list, copy or delete them?

There may be other issues here, but one is that your path for Android has problems. First, as with many other operating systems, Android uses / for path separators, not . Second, /storage/Download will not exist on most Android devices. /storage/emulated/0/Download is substantially more likely.

You don't need to root your phone if the app you are inspecting has android:debuggable=true set. Then you can use the run-as way mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876731/150978 Note that the adb backup way no longer works.

Nice input! @CommonsWare is there no way to know what kind of path will actually be used by Appium? /storage/emulated/0/Download worked in my case, but I will be using other devices. I currently plan to use an app called OI File Manager because it does give me this path at the top, but if I can avoid it, the better.

"/storage/emulated/0/Download worked in my case, but I will be using other devices" -- that path is likely to be fine for just about any ordinary phone or tablet. If you are testing more specialized Android environments, there may or may not be a Download directory at all, let alone at an Appium-accessible path.
