# Android 'debuggable' default value

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to get application's debuggable attribute value from code:

```
packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);           
int flags = packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags;
isDebugMode = (flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;
```

And I have noticed that when debuggable attribute is not specified in manifest this code defines it as true. And documentation says that it is false by default.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) : ( SDK Tools, Revision 8 (December 2010) )

> Support for a true debug build.
>   Developers no longer need to add the
>   *`android:debuggable`* attribute to the
>   *`<application>`* tag in the manifest —
>   **the build tools add the attribute automatically**. In Eclipse/ADT, **all
>   incremental builds are assumed to be
>   debug builds**, so the tools insert
>   *`android:debuggable="true"`*. When
>   exporting **a signed release build,
>   the tools do not add the attribute**.
>   In Ant, a *`ant debug`* command
>   **automatically inserts the
>   android:debuggable="true"** attribute,
>   while *`ant release`* does not. If android:debuggable="true" is manually
>   set, then *`ant release`* will actually do
>   a debug build, rather than a release
>   build.

Comment: any info about gradle in 2018? Same story