# Google Play not accepting APK

Tags: android, apk

I got this error: You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Yet android:debuggable="false" is in my application tag.

### Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg.troopScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_troop_screen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg.defenseScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_defense_screen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg.resourceScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_resource_screen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg.armyScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_army_screen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="icykum.JasonSafaiyeh.cocg.otherScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_other_screen" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Have you recompiled the apk after adding that?

Comment: Yes, and I still got the upload error.

Comment: [Check out this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701343/android-debuggable-default-value) 

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new Keystore first.

For **Android Studio**: 
 Build > Generate Signed APK > Create new keystore

For **Eclipse** : 
  Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package > Create new keystore

After that compile it and you are done.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the dumb question. i am new to this