# What is the android debuggable default value

Tags: android

What is the default for android debuggable, if I do not specify the value in the manifest file?
Will it depend upon version?

What is the default value it is going to take.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 'debuggable' default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701343/android-debuggable-default-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[android:debuggable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug)

> Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device in user mode — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. **The default value is "false".**

No mention of difference in API level, so min/target SDK versions of your app should not matter.