# Android Studio 1.4 won't build APKs when "debuggable true"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm stumbling into the second weird problem within a very short time. Not sure what's going on right now but I have to fix this.

I have an Android Studio Project and in the past I already generated APKs (debug and release ones). Now, I cannot build APKs if debuggable is set to true.

When I modify "release" for debuggable true, it builds but I cannot upload it to the play store:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable true
    }

}
```

Now, as I desperately need to upload this update to the play store, which only lets me do that if this very flag is set to false. I'm running version 1.4 on a Mac OSX 10.11

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `debuggable false` is required for apk to be uploaded on playstore.

Comment: "Now, I couldn't build a release APK" -- please explain, **completely and precisely**, what this means. "it only builds an APK (either one) if debuggable is set to false" -- that is the default state for the `release` build type. The `debug` build type has `debuggable` set to `true`; the `release` build type has `debuggable` set to `false`.

Comment: visit here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5701672/5202007

Comment: I am sorry. I got stuff mixed up. The release build works when I manually set debuggable to true. The problem then is that I do not meet the play store requirement Tauqir mentioned. I corrected my post