# See Shared preference xml file in Real Device During Debugging

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an android application in which I have to save image names in shared preferences via string format.

I am able to see my shared preference xml file in Android Device Monitor but I want to see it in my real android device. I have searched in android device local data neither I am seeing my application package name nor xml file anywhere during debugging.

Please help me why I can't see my application package in mobile device during debugging.

Comment: Check out Stetho. Great tool

Answer (score 1):

> SharedPreferences are stored in an xml file in the app data folder,
>   i.e. `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`
>
> or the default preferences at:
>   `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml`

from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146207/4738175)

However, you can also use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to access your `sharedpreferences` in debug mode. ie you can view `sharedPreferences` from your chrome browser.

`Stetho` can :

- view and edit `SharedPreferences`
- view and edit sqlite db
- monitor network requests
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have root permission to see the sharedpreferences of your app in real device,

**Steps**

1.Root your phone(for rooting phone i would suggest kingo root mobile app)

2.install Root browser/Root explorer   app

3.go to folder  data-->data-->your packagename-->shared_prefs-->your shared prefs name

Comment: It's possible to access private files via `adb` for debuggable applications with `run-as <package-name>` command (without root access). Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811615/how-to-access-the-database-when-developing-on-android-phone/8433520#8433520