# File.list() returns null for directory

Tags: java, android, file-io

When executing the code

```
File path = new File("/data");
boolean isDir = path.isDirectory();
//isDir is true
String[] fList = path.list();
//fList == null!
```

on an Android 2.3 emulator, the file list is null. This seems to contradict the statement from the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list():

```
Returns null if this file is not a directory.
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access `/data` dir since you don't have root access. Without root privileges you can access just an external storage and your app's dir at internal storage.
Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043722/1037294

Comment: thanks for the hint. How should I check for the permissions given a directory path?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to, because you already know what files you can access. Read this short paragraph: [User IDs and File Access](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid)