# Can any body access the database files stored in application's data folder in android?

Tags: android

I am using the SQLite database to store data in my application. Can the databases I created for use in my application be accessed by others or any outside application?

Comment: If you created the database as PRIVATE, then it can be seen but it will not be readable and other applications can not access it.

Comment: Dear Alborz how to see that files in device?

Comment: Here is a long discussion about the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043322/why-do-i-get-access-denied-to-data-folder-when-using-adb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The databse file is stored in /data/data/yourpackage.yourapp/database. On a non rooted phone, you don't even have file system access there. Other Applications can not access this file as well, for very good security reasons.

If you want to share data with other applications or want to consume data from other applications, check

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html