# react-native (android): best practise to store media files?

Tags: android, react-native

I'd like to **store media files** (e.g. *.mp3), captured with my app, locally on the device (e.g. smartphone) and **accessible via the file browser**.

By default I got recommended the `DocumentDirectoryPath`   (`/data/data/org.xxx.yyy/files`). Unfortunately, this directory is only accessible by the app itself, if the device is **not rooted** ([how to read the data via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043322/why-do-i-get-access-denied-to-data-folder-when-using-adb)).

I was thinking about changing the directory to `/Android/data/org.xxx.yyy/files`, but I'm not sure if it's a good practise as I'm not able to save files via `file://Android/data/org.xxx.yyy/files/testfile.txt` *(don't know why, yet)*.

I'd like to use a common way to cover as much devices and android versions as possible. **Where should I store the files?**

*Please note: this question is easily understood as "opinion-based", but I'm really looking for common guidelines.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/Android/data/org.xxx.yyy/files,` That path does not exist to begin with. Have a look at `getExternalFilesDir()` to see the full path. Have a look st `getExternalStorageDirectory()` too.