# How to access my app's SQLite database in android device emulator for debugging

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-7.1-nougat

I'm trying to convert my app to be compatible with API 25 (Nougat). But when I try to use adb shell to go to my app's databases folder inside the virtual device, it wouldn't let me. It says Permission denied.

I tried

```
adb shell
cd data/data/<my app's name>/databases
```

I use the same procedure on API 23 virtual device and it works.

Also, are all nougats not rooted, even in emulators?
I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 and I created the virtual device using the its built-in AVD.

Comment: open Android Studio as **Administrator** and see is it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i find this to be working:

```
adb root shell
adb shell
```

Then I'm able to navigate to my app's database folder and open it.

Comment: When creating and emulator you have to select a system image that does not has Google API, like Intel x86 image, as the Image containing Google API is a production build and you would not get access to root folders, however if you are using the other Images that I mentioned along with the "adb root shell" command you would be able to access the databases in the application folder

Answer (score 0):

You must run ADB in *root mode* to get access to database folder.

Check this link - [Why do I get access denied to data folder when using adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043322/why-do-i-get-access-denied-to-data-folder-when-using-adb)

**EDIT**

Here is what I found---

You were already in the root mode in API 23 and that is why you were able to access the database there but for API 25 you were not.

For API 23

> G:\android_studio_new\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
>
> **root**@generic_x86:/
>   #

For API 25(Nougat)

> G:\android_studio_new\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
>
> generic_x86:/ $

Comment: All API 25 (Nougat) virtual devices that I create are not rooted. I don't know how to create a rooted virtual device by default in API 25. However all API 23 and below virtual devices that I create have root access. And I have no problem opening my SQLite databases when I'm using API 23.

Comment: Let me myself check if could open database in API 25 devices

Comment: Could you please accept or upvote my answer(if you are satisfied). Thank you.