# Unable to cat a file in a subdirectory of /data/user/0 of Android device

Tags: android, file, security, adb, permission-denied

In Android adb shell, I'm unable to `cat` a file in a subdirectory of `/data/user/0`.  The error I get is `Permission denied`.

The `ls` command on `/data/user/0` also returns `Permission denied`.

Is there any way around this, so I can see the content of the file?

Answer (score 3):

Further digging reveals that there's a way to achieve this without having root permission if the file belongs to an app that's installed as a debug build.  Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712173/369722).

In a nutshell:

First, `run-as com.foo.app`.
Current directory will switch to `/data/data/com.foo.app`.
Now you can perform permission restricted commands on subdirectories and files, such as `cat` and `ls`.

Comment: This way you can get access to /data/data/com.foo.app, not to the /data/user/0

Comment: @KirylTkach You're right!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to browse everything like this on your device you need to make your phone with root access to browse the data folders and you need to run `adb root` instead (in root mode)